# Make an MSI to deploy reg key

Tags: visual-studio, registry, windows-installer, key, registrykey

I want to make a .msi file which will allow to install one reg key. Is it easy ? Do you have a clue ?
Thank you by advance and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on setup project -> View -> Registry. Choose where to add your key

Comment: Thank you very much but what can I do if my .reg file have already a reg path ?

Comment: I'don't remember, i think it'll override it but if you want to full control this process you can and one more library with class System.Configuration.Install.Installer and derived from [RunInstaller(true)] attribute and override Install/Unistall methods and then choose this library in custom action of you setup project (view -> custom actions)

Comment: You are welcome! Have you tried basic functionality or made custom action class?